# Are the file paths inside a db table?

Tags: database, magento2.3

Does someone know if some file paths are stored in the database? I created 2 environments and exported one database to another but on the second environment I get the following error: 
 exception(s):

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Magento_Backend::page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'require.js'

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Magento_Backend::page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'require.js'
#0 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(307): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView(false)
#1 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(668): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#2 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(249): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#3 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#4 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#5 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#6 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#7 /var/www/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#8 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#9 /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#10 /var/www/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#11 {main}
```

So because this is a core module I thing that maby there is a table that stores the paths. I tried setup:upgrade, static-content:deploy, reindexing, ... but nothing seems to work. I looked in the Database but can't find table with paths.

Comment: There may be some problem in copying the files. Can you run **php bin/magento setup:di:compile** to see whether the error still appears?

Answer (score 1):

- Template file paths are not stored in the database.
- If you are indeed missing some files from core consider re-updating magento core.
- You can use composer for that. Remove vendor/magento and then composer update. (create backup first, do not this if you have manual changes in the core that you want to keep)
- There also might be the possibility that your custom modules are using a core block/template in an incorrect manner or without providing proper params.